# Performance test tool for GPU drivers Open source Mali/UMP

Tags: linux-kernel, gpu, linux-device-driver, device-driver, mali

I am using ARMv7 TV Board, having board specific GPU driver mali400x4 (OpenGL ES 1.1, 2.0 and OpenVG 1.1). I would like to know any test project suite to test performance, stress, Lmbench for this driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glean and Piglit  OpenGL driver testing tools

Glean-> 1) evaluating the quality of OpenGL. 
Piglit -> 1) Helps to improve quality of openGL driver by regression tests.

Piglit OpenGL Driver Testing Framework Now Works with ARM Linux

Read more: 
http://www.cnx-software.com/2013/01/09/piglit-opengl-driver-testing-framework-now-works-with-arm-linux-opengl-es/